# Parser Error Message: Could not load the assembly 'App_Web__XXXXX'. Make sure that it is compiled before accessing the page

Tags: c#, web-services, iis-8

Error is

> Line 1:  <%@ control language="c#"
>   inherits="Infragistics.WebUI.Samples.AJAX.Progress, App_Web_XXXXX" %>
>   Line 2:   .emptyProgress{
>   background-color:white; width:8px;border-style:solid;border-width:1px;
>   } Line 3:     .progress{ background-color:#00ff00;
>   width:8px;border-style:solid;border-width:1px; }

What I have tried so far :

1)Cleanesd all the temp files from "C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files"

2)Tried [Could not load the assembly 'App_Web_kh7-x3ka'. Make sure that it is compiled before accessing the page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/295919/could-not-load-the-assembly-app-web-kh7-x3ka-make-sure-that-it-is-compiled-be)

3) Making sure appPools point to correct version of CLR.

FYI I can't make changes to source code as I just have folder with files to be deployed.

Answer (score 0):

It seems the problem got resolved , I just removed my **Convert to Application** stuff from my virtual dir and it took all the configuration settings from parent folder and worked fine.