# could not load assembly. Make sure that it is compiled before accessing the page

Tags: asp.net, dll, deployment, build, iis-7

PROBLEM: My project is developed in V4.0 but due to IIS version on UAT server is V2.0 , I have build all .dll in V2.0.

now I have deployed dll to server, but when I click on any page its giving me error like "Could not load the assembly 'App_Web_xxxxxxxxx' . Make sure that it is compiled before accessing the page" highlighting below.

I don't want to change IIS version.

can any one please help to this issue.

THanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Could not load the assembly 'App\_Web\_kh7-x3ka'. Make sure that it is compiled before accessing the page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/295919/could-not-load-the-assembly-app-web-kh7-x3ka-make-sure-that-it-is-compiled-be)

Comment: @VDWWD: actually this "Could not load the assembly 'App_Web_kh7-x3ka' use when you copy files form server to dev location. but in my case issue is on server only. I think both parametsr are ok <%@ page language="c#" autoeventwireup="false" inherits="XXXX.frmXXXX, App_Web_xxx.XXXX" %>

Comment: @VDWWD: even I am selecting precompile option while publishing dlls.

Comment: If you google "could not load assembly. Make sure that it is compiled before accessing the page" there are a ton of other hits, even on SO.

Comment: not finding clear solution.